# Magento 2: Before Place Order Give Error Message

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, error, magento2.1.6

I need to put my custom validation before place order.

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before"> 
        <observer name="check_price" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\BeforePlaceOrderObserver" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Observer\BeforePlaceOrderObserver.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class BeforePlaceOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        die("Error Message");
        exit;
    }
}
```

It still places order. Need to used `$this->_messageManager->addError(__('Error'))`

Comment: Did you try plugin for before method ?

Comment: Nope I only tried observer. If we can achieve using Plugin then can go ahead with that also

Comment: Okay. I think you should try using plugin.

Comment: Which file & function need to use?

Comment: You can refer example here http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-before-after-method-event-observer-using-plugin/

Comment: I know how to create plugin. Need file & function for same

Comment: `sales_order_place_before`   does not prevent from ordering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally It works :)

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement" type="Custom\Module\Model\PaymentInformationManagement" />
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\PaymentInformationManagement.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

class PaymentInformationManagement extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement {

    public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder($cartId, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null) {
        if(<your condition){
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Error'));
                return false;
        }else{
            $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
            try {
                $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'), $e
                );
            }
            return $orderId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not get success. its not working

Answer (score 1):

Place order action using API area.

Move events.xml to webapi_rest folder.
And modify your code:

```
class OrderPlaceBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_messageManager;

    /**
     * OrderPlaceBefore constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {

        $this->_messageManager->addError('Error Message');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working fine